Reason behind transposition restrictions in the BLAS interface
I wonder if there is some reason behind the restrictions in the BLAS interface regarding transposition. Unlike gemm, not all routines allow all combinations of transpositions of the input matrices. For example, symm lets you compute C = A*B or C = B*A, where A is symmetric, but not C = B^T*A. And syr2k lets you compute C = A^T*B + B^T*A and C = A*B^T + B*A^T, but not C = A*B + B^T*A^T.
